# Error: Convert class to functional component using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to convert a class component to hooks, but I'm not able to pass the reference from the flatlist to hooks. Can someone help me?

full code: https://snack.expo.io/SJs3a0JwU

code:

```
  ...
this.flatList.scrollToOffset({animated: true, offset: scrollValue});
 }, 3000);

  ...

   <FlatList
      data={data}
      ref={flatList => {
        this.flatList = flatList; //here

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the useRef hook, that will keep your reference stored:

```
 const flatList = useRef(null);
 // rest of the code
 <FlatList
  data={data}
  ref={flatList}
 />
```

And now if you want to access to the dom reference you can do `flatList.current.scrollToOffset({animated: true, offset: scrollValue});`

Comment: Cant find find variable flatlist

Comment: where did you declared it?

Comment: above useEffect

Comment: Ok I tweaked your example a little bit, moving the infiniteScroll function inside your component, does this works? https://snack.expo.io/SJztNJewI

Comment: I couldn't see it, it's the same way for me